# Tightening the bolts on training wheels for a child's Schwin bike

Tags: wheels, children

My child is learning to ride his first bike and I have attached the training wheels to help him learn to balance.  I have adjusted them to be slightly off the ground so he can get used to the feeling of balancing.  My issue:  The wheels simply won't stay in place for longer than a single ride.  I notice that as my son rides and the wheels take his weight they slide up and then he risks falling on that side..

Beyond the risk of over tightening the bolts using an electric tool is there any other method of ensuring the wheels do not slip?

Comment: Have you seen your kid balance with the training wheels? All kids I see that use them use the bike as a trike, always on three wheels. My suggestion is not to use the wheels, it will take a few days but then you never have to adjust them anymore because your kid does not need them.

Comment: Not an answer, but training wheels are considered an old way of teaching balance.  The current best-practice is a Balance Bike (a Run Bike) and scootering about. Training wheels teach reliance on the two outrigger wheels, making the whole process take much longer.   Search the site for "balance bike" and read about it yourself.

Comment: Is it possible your fixing nuts are running out of thread?  You might need a couple of strategic washers on the axle ends.

Comment: @Criggie's right but if yours, like mine, refuses to get on a balance bike because it hasn't got pedals and isn't proper like daddy's, just do what works for you and don't worry

Comment: @ChrisH.child  "you can ride a daddy-bike when you show daddy that you can balance.  You have to coast from here to there without touching the ground"  say 5 metres or whatever's convenient.  I'm happy if the balance bike only gets used for 10 minutes total, as long as it teaches balance.  Plus bike can be handed onto the next kid.

Comment: Did try the balance bike.  He has a mental block associating his pedal bike to the balance bike.  I might give that a try again though and just run him around a field till he gets the hang of it.

Comment: Make a balance bike out of this one: Remove the pedals and lower the saddle until the youngsters toes reach the ground and a little further down. Do the same with your bike to show him (if it's possible). Make a game out of it.

Comment: I like the idea Carel.  Appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: The comparison with Daddy bike is not right with side wheels either. Yours does not have side wheels, the kids bike does not need them either. People of my generation never had them and we all learned to ride.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer - do the bolts up tighter.

Bolts for training wheels are pretty hefty, it's hard to over tighten them with a hand wrench.

If you don't have a suitably long wrench that will allow you to get the torque you need, you can extend the wrench handle with a length of metal pipe. Avoid using an adjustable wrench as these can round the bolt heads off. Not everyone has a length of pipe laying around of course. Any good bike shop will tighten the bolts for free or a nominally low charge.

Comment: The best thing you can do is to get a proper ring spanner/wrench so that you won't round the bolts.

Comment: Or use a socket spanner

Comment: Tried the socket wrench (spanner) but it the head on the nut pushed too far into the socket.

Comment: @user38062 Recesses in socket wrenches are typically deeper than a nut or bolt head. That does not prevent tightening.

Comment: Besides being tight you must have the correct hardware. Most training wheels use a flanged nut to hold the on. This applies the load over a larger area hold them in position longer.

Answer (score 2):

The training wheel bracket is shaped like a C. Inside the bracket should be a C shaped 'washer' which has a small tab. The tab is suppose to go in the slot the wheel axle is on. With the 'washer' in place, the bracket will try to twist but the tab will stop it. 
I am guessing if you do have this washer, it is not installed correctly. Your local bike shop (LBS) should be able to show you how to set the training wheels.

As mentioned, the balance bike method is also worth trying. Remove the training wheels and the bike's pedals. Then drop the seat so they can put their feet down while sitting. ta da, balance bike.

Comment: I'll take a look at the configuration and confirm if the washer/tab set up is correct.  Great suggestion